# .htaccess prevent changes rewritten url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following .htaccess rewirite rule:

```
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (/m)?/([^/]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
      RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/user/upload%1/%2.%3
```

So, now link transforms (like redirect) from `http://domain.com/12345.png` to `http://domain.com/user/upload/12345.png`.

What have I to fix (I think, it should be some flag), if I want to prevent this transformation?

Comment: You could add `[P]` at the end, but this is generally not a good idea, unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `http://domain.com` from the target of your rule:

```
RewriteRule .* /user/upload%1/%2.%3 [L]
```